# Magento Event Observer Change Cart Base Subtotal

Tags: magento

I've been trying to get this right for the past couple of days. I've read so many posts I am sure I am close (or at least close at some point) but I just can't seem to get this. I am using the even observer `checkout_cart_save_after` Here is what I am doing inside of the `checkout_cart_save_after`

```
$session = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session');
$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
$quote->setBaseSubtotal(0);
$quote->save();
```

All I am trying to do is get the Subtotal to equal 0 ... From what I read I want to set the "BaseSubtotal" because of currency differences. Eventually what I will do with this once I can get it working is dynamically change the price so it's not always going to be 0. But baby steps here lol I just want to try and change the price to specific value first.

Comment: Looks like I finally found something here http://pradeepkumarrcs.blogspot.com/2011/12/applying-custom-discount-amount-in.html ... it appears to work, idk why... Will have to take some time to tear it down and figure it out. I figured adjusting prices would be a bit more simple than this.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to do

```
$quote->setSubtotal(0);      // needs to be there ;)
$quote->setBaseSubtotal(0);
```

An object and a Base objects are two different things and both need to be set.

Comment: So I tried changing it to `$session = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session');`
`$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();`
`$quote->setSubtotal(0);`
`$quote->setBaseSubtotal(0);`
`$quote->save();'` and it still didn't update the total on the checkout page. The Subtotal had still not been set to 0 =\

Comment: I know it sounds redundant but try swapping BaseSub over Sub